# How do I get a variable from JavaScript and use it in the Server side (C#)?

Tags: javascript, c#

Lets say I have a certain variable on the Client-Side (JavaScript):

```js
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
```

I would like to make a conditional (if-else) statement on the server side based on whether isMobile (on the Client-Side) is true or false. In other words, I would like to know how I would get my variable from that JavaScript file and somehow send it to the code behind.

I was thinking on the server side it would be something simple along the lines of this:

```
<---------------Server Side Code (C#)---------------------->
if (isMobile == false)
{
Console.WriteLine("This isnt Mobile");
Console.ReadLine();
V = BLUE;
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("This IS Mobile");
Console.ReadLine();
V = RED;            
<---------------End Server Side Code (C#)---------------------->
```

/*(RED and BLUE are just some random variables I have in my actual code but     haven't really addressed here, as I thought it was trivial. They can be
ignored...) */ }

But I am not sure how to go about referencing it or sending the client side data to the server side.

**Things I've seen or tried but with no success:**

*I have read similar examples but they involved functions being referenced like this*:            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "~/myScriptPage.js", "myFunction();", true);

*I have also seen things like this*:var x = HttpContext.Current.Session["Variable"];
This seemed like it would work at first but I guess I do not really understand how to use this in my situation.

*I have also read about using ajax and not really being able to interact between client side and server side without sending and HTTP request to the server and also examples with hidden fields.*

Is there any way to do this using the code above? Does any of this even make sense? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: the code `navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);` could not work in Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 phone devices... Try to search how Microsoft Edge's user agent will be...

Comment: Have you tried using PageMethods ?

Comment: I think you should read up on RESTful interfaces and how to transfer JSON/XML between the client and the server

Comment: You could use a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

You can get User Agent from c# code using:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent
```

and you can do regex tests using:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch()
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use a MVC pattern, you may create a hidden field like:

```
@Html.Hidden("IsMobile","false");
```

or using a Model like:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsMobile)
```

At client-side, you may use:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var ism = isMobile();
  $('#IsMobile').val(ism);
});

function isMobile() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
}
}
</script>
```

"IsMobile" function I have been copied by other stackoverflow answer from [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)